# How to pass connection string with special characters as a parameter to PowerShell task in Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell

I am trying to pass connection string to power-shell task as an argument but it 
gives error:

> Cannot convert value to type System.String

Sample connectionstring:

```
Data Source=abc:abc-abc-abc-abc.abc.abc.abc,7458;Abc abc=abc;abc ac=ac-abc@abc-abc-ab-ab;Abc=Abc#345abc;Abc Ab=60
```

Calling:

```
-BlueConnection $(CONNECTION_BLUE) -GreenConnection $(CONNECTION_GREEN)
```

Powershell file abc.ps1

```
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
[string]$BlueConnection,
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
[string]$GreenConnection
)

echo "Hi  $BlueConnection"
```

gives below error:

> Cannot convert value to type System.String

Comment: Try to add quotes around the connectionstring, this might be the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-BlueConnection $(CONNECTION_BLUE) -GreenConnection $(CONNECTION_GREEN)` should be `-BlueConnection "$(CONNECTION_BLUE)" -GreenConnection "$(CONNECTION_GREEN)"`

Just like any time you're passing command line arguments, you need to wrap it in quotes if it contains spaces or special characters.