# AzureDevOps Powershell task command line parameters are not properly rendered in Powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I have an AzureDevops Powershell task which is passing values read from KeyVault as parameters to the script.  Even with double or single quotes surrounding the variables in the DevOps task, the values do not appear correct in the script.

What else do I need to do to get these values passed properly to the script?

There is an [older similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561416/how-to-pass-connection-string-with-special-characters-as-a-parameter-to-powershe) and the answer was to double-quote the parameters in the task, which I've done, to no avail.

Sample Powershell task:

```
ScriptArguments: -connectionString "$(ConnString)" -password "$(ConnStringPassword)"
```

Sample values stored in KeyVault:

```
ConnString:  Server=tcp:test-sqldb.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=TestDb;Persist Security Info=False;
ConnStringPassword:  Pa$$w0rd
```

Sample Script:

```
param (
  [string]$connectionString,
  [string]$password
)

Write-Host "connectionString: $connectionString"
Write-Host "password: $password"
```

Sample output from pipeline execution:

```
connectionString: ***
password: Paw0rd
```

If I use single quotes in the pipeline task as suggested by @Thomas below:

Sample Powershell task:

```
ScriptArguments: -connectionString '$(ConnString)' -password '$(ConnStringPassword)'
```

Sample output from Pipeline execution:

```
connectionString: ***
password: ***
```

Comment: Double quotes allow PS to evaluate the content, thus interpreting `$` signs as the beginning of a variable name. Try single quotes instead.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, tried that as well.  Posted further results above.  Similar issue though.

Comment: How about `ScriptArguments: ' -connectionString "$(ConnString)" -password "$(ConnStringPassword)"'`? (adding single quotes around the whole thing)

Comment: The values from KeyVault came as *secrets*, you can't see the values.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk That is the only thing that seems to make sense, but if that is the case, why does the first sample output above show the password value (a bit messed up though because of the $$).  And is the bottom line that I can't use these values in my Powershell script?  In the actual script output when I attempt to use these values, '***' is still what ends up in the output, not the connection string from KeyVault.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Update: you are 100% correct.  I validated that KV values are properly utilized in the Powershell script by doing a publish step on a test output file.  See the answer I posted and a link within for further reference.  Thanks for engaging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ShaykiAbramczyk is correct, secrets are not viewable.  The values are however being properly utilized in the Powershell script.  I verified this by publishing a test output file and seeing that the KeyVault values are in the output file.  The following reference gave me the idea to publish to see the values as opposed to trying to echo or write them to the console.

[Use secrets from Azure Key Vault in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Hi @Mike, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. Have a nice day. :)